# deleting specific .lnk files deletes all .lnk files

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to delete a specific .lnk file from the startup folder, meaning a file with the exact name.

Code I'm using:

```
cd %AllUsersProfile%\Start Menu\Programs
setlocal enableextensions
del /s /f /q calc.lnk >>"C:\deleted.log"
```

However when using this, ALL .lnk files in that folder get deleted. Without the /s switch, this behaviour does not occur but then the deletion isn't being logged...

I have tried with putting the filename in quotes "calc.lnk" or the full path:

```
del /s /f /q "%AllUsersProfile%\Start Menu\Programs\calc.lnk" >>"C:\deleted.log"
```

And again in both cases all .lnk files get deleted... I only want calc.lnk deleted and logged when it is deleted.

Any clues? Thanks..

Comment: what the name of another ink in your paths?

Comment: It can be any other link honestly, the name makes no difference :( so it can be calc2.lnk or random.lnk and they all get deleted.